# Android : Permissions check for BLE

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-permissions

To use Bluetooth Low Energy in an Android App it is necessary to include multiple permissions in the Manifest and a runtime check the user has approved these permissions

The issue is there are 6 possible permissions but attempting to check all the permissions will fail! This is because runtime permissions are never granted for some versions of Android.

The 6 permissions are

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

A big thank you to @Kozmotronik for the simple solution of only checking permissions required by each version of Android

The following checks the required permissions and if not already granted adds to a list. It then requests the missing permissions.

```kt
private fun checkAndRequestMissingPermissions() {
    // check required permissions - request those which have not already been granted
    val missingPermissionsToBeRequested = ArrayList<String>()
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        missingPermissionsToBeRequested.add(Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH)

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        missingPermissionsToBeRequested.add(Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN)

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
        // For Android 12 and above require both BLUETOOTH_CONNECT and BLUETOOTH_SCAN
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            missingPermissionsToBeRequested.add(Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT)
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            missingPermissionsToBeRequested.add(Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN)
    }

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        // FINE_LOCATION is needed for Android 10 and above
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            missingPermissionsToBeRequested.add(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
    } else {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            missingPermissionsToBeRequested.add(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
    }

    if (missingPermissionsToBeRequested.isNotEmpty()) {
        writeToLog("Missing the following permissions: $missingPermissionsToBeRequested")
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, missingPermissionsToBeRequested.toArray(arrayOfNulls<String>(0)), REQUEST_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS)
    } else {
        writeToLog("All required permissions GRANTED !")
    }

}
```

onRequestPermissionsResult() can then check the user has approved the required permissions

```
override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS) {
        for (idx in permissions.indices) {
            var result = if (grantResults[idx] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) "Granted" else "Denied"
            writeToLog("REQUEST_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS Permission ${permissions[idx]} $result}")
        }
    }
}
```

Android requires a permission check before giving access to some BLE functions. Where the permission will not be granted it must still be checked, but can be made to work by adding a check of the Android version.

For example

```kt
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    writeToLog("Scan permission denied")
} else {
    bluetoothScanner.startScan(filters, scanSettings, scanCallback)
    writeToLog("Bluetooth Scan Started")
}
```

Recently @Kozmotronik has improved his answer which is shown below

Comment: Not all those permissions are needed for all API levels. For example `BLUETOOTH_CONNECT` and `BLUETOOTH_SCAN` permissions don't apply the API levels below API 31 - Android 12. What are your **min** and **max** target APIs?

Comment: @Kozmotronik minSdk 28 and targetSdk 31. 
But how do you get past the Google errors for each use?
e.g. if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.S) { 
         bluetoothScanner.startScan(null, scanSettings, scanCallback) // don't need _SCAN BUT this line is still marked as an error 
     } else if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {              
         bluetoothScanner.startScan(null, scanSettings, scanCallback)
     }

Comment: They are actually warnings more than errors. If you block all the **call pathways** to those APIs with permission checks, you won't have any problems. Also make sure you request the permissions in your activity. Unfortunately if the `SCAN` and `CONNECT` permissions are rejected once, `shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale` is not being called for them. That's what I experienced. So in case of the user deny the permissions, you're supposed to inform the user about that the app usage will be limited because of the denied permissions and encourage them to allow.

Comment: I will show you an example about how to add permission checks in the call pathway of the APIs in my free time.

Comment: Hi @RatherBeSailing, hope you are doing well. I've posted another answer based on my first answer's example code. The new one however, shows how to request BLE permissions using the newer `ActivityResultLauncher` API. I would be grateful if you could post another answer where you convert my new example to kotlin code.

Comment: @Kozmotronik I will be unable to post an answer because someone has closed the question ... I was due to revisit my BLE code as my current App runs perfectly on Android 31 but continuously disconnects when run on Android 33!

Comment: Yes unfortunately. But it can be reversed by pointing out the problem well. Do you mind? I thought to do this, however I worried about changing the original context of the question and make it a different thing. In contrast, there will be no context changing problem if you do it yourself since it is originated from your mind. I suggest you to consider it just because this is an important topic on Android bluetooth programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google made Android more strict by adding the new `BLUETOOTH_CONNECT` and `BLUETOOTH_SCAN` permissions. You will get `SecurityException` in runtime if you attempt to access any BLE API that requires these permissions. So we need to check the permissions in the activity which is set to `android.intent.action.MAIN` in the manifest file. I call that as `MainActivity`. Unfortunately I don't code in Kotlin yet, so I will write the examples in Java.

**MainActivity**

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static int BLE_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE = 0x55; // Could be any other positive integer value
    private int permissionsCount;
    //...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Other codes...
        checkBlePermissions();

        // Maybe some more codes...
    }

    // Maybe some other codes...

    private String getMissingLocationPermission() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M
                && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            // COARSE is needed for Android 6 to Android 10
            return Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION;
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            // FINE is needed for Android 10 and above
            return Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;
        }
        // No location permission is needed for Android 6 and below
        return null;
    }

    private boolean hasLocationPermission(String locPermission) {
        if(locPermission == null) return true; // An Android version that doesn't need a location permission
        return ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), locPermission) ==
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }


    private String[] getMissingBlePermissions() {
        String[] missingPermissions = null;

        String locationPermission = getMissingLocationPermission();
        // For Android 12 and above
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
            if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                missingPermissions = new String[1];
                missingPermissions[0] = Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN;
            }

            if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (missingPermissions == null) {
                    missingPermissions = new String[1];
                    missingPermissions[0] = Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT;
                } else {
                    missingPermissions = Arrays.copyOf(missingPermissions, missingPermissions.length + 1);
                    missingPermissions[missingPermissions.length-1] = Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT;
                }
            }

        }
        else if(!hasLocationPermission(locationPermission)) {
            missingPermissions = new String[1];
            missingPermissions[0] = getMissingLocationPermission();
        }
        return missingPermissions;
    }

    private void checkBlePermissions() {
        String[] missingPermissions = getMissingBlePermissions();
        if(missingPermissions == null || missingPermissions.length == 0) {
            Log.i(TAG, "checkBlePermissions: Permissions is already granted");
            return;
        }

        for(String perm : missingPermissions)
            Log.d(TAG, "checkBlePermissions: missing permissions "+perm);
        permissionsCount = missingPermissions.length;

        requestPermissions(missingPermissions, BLE_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    // Maybe some other codes...

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if(requestCode == BLE_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE) {
            int index = 0;
            for(int result: grantResults) {
                if(result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Permission granted for "+permissions[index]);
                    if(permissionsCount > 0) permissionsCount--;
                    if(permissionsCount == 0) {
                        // All permissions have been granted from user.
                        // Here you can notify other parts of the app ie. using a custom callback or a viewmodel so on.
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Permission denied for "+permissions[index]);
                    // TODO handle user denial i.e. show an informing dialog
                }
            }
        } else {
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
}
```

We are done with requesting the all needed permissions depending on the device's SDK so far. Now we need to block the API call pathways to be able to check the permissions. Somewhere where you implement bluetooth scanning put a function like `startScanning()` as in the code example below, instead of using the `BleScanner.scan()` API directly. All the following functions must be in the same activity or fragment.

**Another activity or fragment where scanning is implemented**

```java
private String getMissingLocationPermission() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M
            && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        // COARSE is needed for Android 6 to Android 10
        return Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION;
    } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        // FINE is needed for Android 10 and above
        return Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;
    }
    // No location permission is needed for Android 6 and below
    return null;
}

private boolean hasLocationPermission() {
    String missingLocationPermission = getMissingLocationPermission();
    if(missingLocationPermission == null) return true; // No permissions needed
    return ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(requireContext(), missingLocationPermission) ==
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
}

private boolean checkLocationService(@Nullable Runnable r) {
    boolean locationServiceState = isLocationServiceEnabled();
    String stateVerbose = locationServiceState ? "Location is on" : "Location is off";
    Log.d(TAG, stateVerbose);
    if(!locationServiceState){

        new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(requireContext())
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setTitle("Location Service Off")
                .setView("Location service must be enabled in order to scan the bluetooth devices.")
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, (dialog, which) ->
                        startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS)))
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, (dialog, which) -> {
                    if(r != null) r.run();
                })
                .create().show();
    }
    return  locationServiceState;
}

private boolean isLocationServiceEnabled(){
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P){
        // This is provided as of API 28
        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) requireContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        return lm.isLocationServiceEnabled();
    } else {
        // This is deprecated as of API 28
        int mod = Settings.Secure.getInt(requireContext().getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE,
                Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_OFF);
        return (mod != Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_OFF);
    }
}

private void startScanning() {
    // Here we intervene the scanning process and check whether the user allowed us to use location.
    if(!hasLocationPermission()) {
        // Here you have to request the approprite location permission similar to that main activity class
        return;
    }
    // Location service must be enabled
    if(!checkLocationService(() -> // Pass a Runnable that starts scanning)) return;

    // Everything is good, CAN START SCANNING
}
```

This logic is a little confusing by nature but it is robust and have been running in a [real application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.himtec.himtec_kontrol) that presents in Google Play Store. However It is not 100% complete code since you need to adapt the idea behind it to your application.

Comment: a big and genuine thank you. You pointed me in the right direction and this afternoon I finally restored some BLE functionality. I have updated the question so hopefully others can benefit from your expertise (is there a better way of referencing you in the text?)

Comment: I have updated my code samples incorporating your advice - Is there a better way of acknowledging your input other than the comment? While not shown in my application various user Buttons are disabled by default and are only enabled once all permissions are obtained.

Comment: *is there a better way of referencing you in the text?* I didn't get how and where you want to reference me. Good to  hear that my solution helped you manage to get your app work although it was in Java . I had to do my own research about these permissoin to manage all the BLE permissions between API 22 - API 32. *Is there a better way of acknowledging your input other than the comment?*.. Well I think you found it and accepted the answer as solution to your problem. You can also upvote the solution if you'd like to.

Comment: Just discovered you can add min max sdk into the manifest - Is this recommended or just another complication? ```<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
                 android:maxSdkVersion="28" />```

Comment: @RatherBeSailing I have no idea about that.

Answer (score 0):

In my previous answer I showed how to deal with BLE permissions for the APIs up to 12 using the old [requestPermissions](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/ActivityCompat#requestPermissions(android.app.Activity,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20int)) to request runtime permissions and finally handle the requested permissions using the [onRequestPermissionsResult](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback#onRequestPermissionsResult(int,java.lang.String%5B%5D,int%5B%5D)) callback.
In this answer I will show how to deal with requesting the same permissions using the newer API called [ActivityResultLauncher](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/result/ActivityResultLauncher) based on the previous code example.
As a bonus I also add an example that shows how to request from user to enable BLE hardware and handle the result using the same API.
So in the end you will be able to request both required runtime BLE permissions and BLE hardware activation using the ActivityResultLauncher API.
**Before getting into the code** please note that the placement of code can vary from application to application depending on its structure. This why you the developer are responsible to place the code in the approprite source file carefully in order to get it functioning issue free.

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private int permissionsCount;
    
    // ActivityResultLauncher for Bluetooth enable request process
    private final ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> bleEnableLauncher
            = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
            result -> {
                if(Activity.RESULT_OK == result.getResultCode()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "User accepted to enable bluetooth");
                    // TODO Trigger a pending scanning or connection
                }
                else if(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED == result.getResultCode()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "User rejected to enable bluetooth");
                    // TODO inform the user that the functionality of the app
                    // is reduced unless he/she decides to accept to enable it.
                }
            });
            
    // ActivityResultLauncher to handle multiple BLE permissions
    private final ActivityResultLauncher<String[]> permissionsResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
            new ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions(),
            permissions -> {
                for(Map.Entry<String, Boolean> permission: permissions.entrySet()) {
                    if(permission.getValue()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Permission granted for "+permission.getKey());
                        if(permissionsCount > 0) permissionsCount--;
                        else {
                            // TODO
                            // All permissions have been granted from user.
                            // Here you can notify other parts of the app ie. using a custom callback or a viewmodel so on.
                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Permission denied for "+permission.getKey());
                        // TODO handle user denial i.e. show an informing dialog
                    }
                }
            }
    );
    //...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Other codes...
        
        // You can alternatively place these check functions in the onResume()
        // callback or before you access the BLE APIs
        checkBleEnabled(); // First check whether bluetooth is enabled
        checkBlePermissions(); // Then check whether the permissions are granted

        // Maybe some more codes...
    }

    // Maybe some other codes...
    
    private void checkBleEnabled() {
        BluetoothManager bluetoothManager = getSystemService(BluetoothManager.class);
        BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();
        if (bluetoothAdapter == null) {
            // TODO Handle -> Device doesn't support Bluetooth, probably
            // you'll want to finish the activity or inform the user then
            // return from here
        }
        if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            bleEnableLauncher.launch(enableBtIntent);
        }
    }

    private String getMissingLocationPermission() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M
                && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            // COARSE is needed for Android 6 to Android 10
            return Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION;
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            // FINE is needed for Android 10 and above
            return Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;
        }
        // No location permission is needed for Android 6 and below
        return null;
    }

    private boolean hasLocationPermission(String locPermission) {
        if(locPermission == null) return true; // An Android version that doesn't need a location permission
        return ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), locPermission) ==
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }


    private String[] getMissingBlePermissions() {
        String[] missingPermissions = null;

        String locationPermission = getMissingLocationPermission();
        // For Android 12 and above
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
            if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                missingPermissions = new String[1];
                missingPermissions[0] = Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN;
            }

            if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (missingPermissions == null) {
                    missingPermissions = new String[1];
                    missingPermissions[0] = Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT;
                } else {
                    missingPermissions = Arrays.copyOf(missingPermissions, missingPermissions.length + 1);
                    missingPermissions[missingPermissions.length-1] = Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT;
                }
            }

        }
        else if(!hasLocationPermission(locationPermission)) {
            missingPermissions = new String[1];
            missingPermissions[0] = getMissingLocationPermission();
        }
        return missingPermissions;
    }

    private void checkBlePermissions() {
        String[] missingPermissions = getMissingBlePermissions();
        if(missingPermissions == null || missingPermissions.length == 0) {
            Log.i(TAG, "checkBlePermissions: Permissions are already granted");
            return;
        }

        for(String perm : missingPermissions)
            Log.d(TAG, "checkBlePermissions: missing permissions "+perm);
        permissionsCount = missingPermissions.length;

        permissionsResultLauncher.launch(missingPermissions);
    }

    // Other codes...
}
```

Feel free to ask in case you're stuck while applying the example to your project.