# BLE scanner on Android 12 not emit devices in Foreground service after phone reboot

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-12

I have Android 10 and Android 12 phones. BLE scanner works fine after rebooting the first one, but doesn't work on the second one.

App has all required permissions requested in runtime:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" android:maxSdkVersion="30"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" android:maxSdkVersion="30"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" android:maxSdkVersion="23"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
```

GPS and Bluetooth are enabled on the phone.

After rebooting, Foreground service is started from the broadcast receiver (`Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED`).

This service then starts the BLE scanner with the scan filter:

```
bleAdapter.bluetoothLeScanner.startScan(filters, settings, callback)
```

It's successfully registered in system (`BluetoothLeScanner: onScannerRegistered() - status=0 scannerId=7 mScannerId=0`), but there are no devices in the scanner callback on Android 12.

What is the reason and how to solve this problem?

Comment: Since you do not document this in your source code examples. Location permissions are [runtime permissions](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/permissions), do you request them at runtime?

Comment: @risto Yes, I request them at runtime. All works fine in foreground and background until 
 launching Android service after rebooting phone. If after rebooting I launch the app, it continues emitting nearby devices.

Comment: Do you mind to add that piece of code where you handle `Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED` in your FG service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BLE scanner in service started after phone reboot requires `android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION` permission at runtime - `Allow all the time` in location permission settings page (not `Allow only while using the app`). It's not enough to only put it in `AndroidManifest`.

More about permission here:
https://developer.android.com/training/location/permissions#request-background-location

Answer (score 0):

Your app is missing the [BLUETOOTH_SCAN](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#BLUETOOTH_SCAN) and [BLUETOOTH_CONNECT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) **runtime** permissions for API 31 and above. The `BLUETOOTH_SCAN` is for accessing the ble scan results and the latter is for accessing and communicating with remote devices, hence makes use of the APIs like [BluetoothDevice](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice). You need to implement this permissions in your code where you access to these APIs. Also have a look at [Target Android 12 or higher](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/permissions#declare-android12-or-higher).

Comment: Sorry, actually I have these runtime permissions, but they are in separate bluetooth gradle module. I just forget to note them here in my question. I've updated the question.

Comment: You see, it matters to share required piece of code. But the question is: Do you check and request those permissions in runtime either using [requestPermissions](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/ActivityCompat#requestPermissions(android.app.Activity,%20java.lang.String[],%20int)) or [ActivityResultLauncher](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/result/ActivityResultLauncher) APIs?

Comment: [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72842249/12749998) from another question may guide you to implement permission handling properly for all APIs.

Comment: I've requested all permissions in runtime as in your answer, and all works fine if user open app at least once. The problem is only after rebooting phone before first app opening.

Comment: Yep you're right. I've missed the rebooting detail. Place a log in your foreground service where you handle the rebooting intent, check these new permissions using `ContexCompat` whether they persist granted after the rebooting process. One posibility is that the permissions are reset on reboot? What else may it be?

Comment: Have you specified the android:foregroundServiceType for your service inside the manifest?