# Bluetooth (BLE) scans throws error code 2

Tags: java, android, android-bluetooth

I'm working on a project right now, no one has been able to solve this error. It only happens on some real devices.

I'm trying to capture bluetooth signals in a dialog. I force bluetooth to be turned on before the dialog opens, I force it to get location information and androidManifest permissions are all there. It works correctly on almost all of the phones used in the project, but in a few of them, the bluetooth scan falls into the onScanFailed method as soon as it starts. It is included as **errorCode 2** in **onScanFailed**. I couldn't find the solution, can you help me?

scan method

```
private void scanForBeacon(){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        mLEScanner = btAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();
        if (btAdapter != null){
            if(btAdapter.isEnabled()){
                beaconList = new ArrayList<BeaconItem>();
                peripheralList = new ArrayList<String>();
                receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                    @Override
                    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                        final String action = intent.getAction();
                        if (action.equals(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED)) {
                            final int state = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE, BluetoothAdapter.ERROR);
                            switch(state) {
                                case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF:
                                    break;
                                case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_OFF:
                                    Handler handler = new Handler();
                                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {
                                            Log.d(TAG, "bluetooth adapter try to enable");
                                            btAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().enable();
                                        }}, 500);
                                    break;
                                case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON:
                                    mLEScanner = btAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();
                                    mLEScanner.startScan(filters, settings, mScanCallback);
                                    break;
                                case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_ON:
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                };
                IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
                getOwnActivity().registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
                settings = new ScanSettings.Builder()
                        .setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY)
                        .build();
                filters = new ArrayList<>();

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    beaconList.clear();
                    peripheralList.clear();
                    btAdapter.startLeScan(leScanCallback);
                } else {
                    try{
                        beaconList.clear();
                        peripheralList.clear();
                        mLEScanner = btAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();
                        mLEScanner.startScan(filters, settings, mScanCallback);
                    }catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("hata", e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            } else{
                getOwnActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Global.showAlert(getOwnActivity(), SweetAlertDialog.ERROR_TYPE, R.string.error, R.string.must_enabled_bt_for_join_attendance, R.string.ok, new SweetAlertDialog.OnSweetClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(SweetAlertDialog sweetAlertDialog) {
                                dismiss();
                                if(timer != null)
                                    timer.cancel();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        }

    }
}
```

onScanFailed

```
@Override
public void onScanFailed(final int errorCode) {
    try{
        if (tryTime == 0){
            mLEScanner.stopScan(mScanCallback);
            btAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().disable();
            tryTime++;
        } else{
            getOwnActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Global.closeLoadingView();
                    Global.showAlert(getOwnActivity(),  SweetAlertDialog.ERROR_TYPE, getString(R.string.error), getString(R.string.cbn_scan_failed).replace("[error_code]", String.valueOf(errorCode)));
                }
            });
        }
    } catch (Exception e){
        try{
            getOwnActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Global.closeLoadingView();
                    Global.showAlert(getOwnActivity(),  SweetAlertDialog.ERROR_TYPE, getString(R.string.error), getString(R.string.cbn_scan_failed).replace("[error_code]", String.valueOf(errorCode)));
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception x){
            x.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I forced bluetooth and location information to be turned on before the dialog opens.

**Some devices with problems**

- Samsung A7 2017
- Tecno spark 5 pro kd7 -> android version 10
- Xiaomi redmi note 9s

Comment: I would recommend using [NordicSemiconductor/Android-Scanner-Compat-Library](https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/Android-Scanner-Compat-Library), which save you a lot of hassle.

Comment: Apart from that, what is your app target SDK version, and what are the android version on the problematic devices? Be aware of the [Android 12 Bluetooth permission changes](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/permissions)

Comment: Well Google's BLE APIs and permissions are a total mess. Ranging from API 23 (Android 6) to API 31, your application has to deal with 4 different runime permissions depending on what API it runs. These permissions are: `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` for between API 23 and 28, `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` for between API 29 and 30, `BLUETOOTH_SCAN` and `BLUETOOTH_SCAN` for 31 and above respectively. Now I raise the question of "Have you handled all these runtime permissions correctly?"

Comment: Have a look at this [mini guide like answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72842249/12749998) about a complete BLE master permission handling if you struggle implementing it.

Comment: I am using all 4 permissions. I think I am asking permission correctly. I'll try @RickyMo 's suggestion. I will keep you informed of the result. Thank you