# Nearby Devices permission

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-bluetooth

Is it possible to automatically allow Nearby Devices permission, or ask the user to allow it upon app start?
Currently, every time I reinstall the app, I have to manually enable it in the phone's settings.

[image]

Comment: for what bluetooth or wifi?

Comment: for bluetooth...

Comment: You must ask to user to allow unless you wanna make your app for personal use only. Check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72842249/12749998) in case of you have trouble on how to implement runtime permissions for bluetooth including all API levels and location service check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this doc your problem will be solved.
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/permissions

Answer (score 3):

According to the documentation, you should ask permission for every new install.
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifi-permissions

Comment: sorry in the question I mean for Bluetooth

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/permissions

Comment: The BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE, BLUETOOTH_CONNECT, and BLUETOOTH_SCAN permissions are runtime permissions.