# location permission missing (code 3) - Android 12

Tags: android, kotlin, location, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-12

I am working for an application which uses BLE technology for pairing and IOT device and uses precises location to perform some specific task related to application requirements

Now, on Android 12 some device (I tested on SAMSUNG SM-M21)
it ended up in error

```
location permission missing (code 3)
```

whereas in another device like Realme, Mi it works fine as expected

After referring to the article
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/permissions

I already added these permission in the Manifest

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"
        android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"
        android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
```

I am already requesting permission at runtime from user

If any more information is needed, please let me know. I will update the question accordingly.

Comment: The use of permisions can be mentioned i manifest file but most of them have to be requested at runtime and confirmid by the user of your app. If you dont do that the user can also give the permisssions in the Settings for your app.

Comment: try to give required permissions manually and check whether it is working fine. If yes you may need to request those permissions in run time.

Comment: @blackapps I m already doing that part at my Kotlin code level, as mentioned in device other than Android 12 samsung it is working fine

Comment: Yes that is normal. For 12 you have to do it differently.

Comment: If your application does not need to run in the background in Android 12, it suffice only the BLUETOOTH_SCAN permission along with a flag set as `android:usesPermissionFlags="neverForLocation"` in the manifest. But looks like you haven't declared `BLUETOOTH_SCAN` perm. in  your manifest while you're supposed to do it on Android 12 and above. Does your app runs in background? Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72842249/12749998) if it helps.

Comment: @Kozmotronik
 Thanks you reference resolved my issues
  you can post your comment as Answer; if want some upvote 

Comment: Never mind @KartikAgarwal, you can answer for your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding this to manifest

```
<uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN"
        android:usesPermissionFlags="neverForLocation" />
```

and at code level added a condition which add extra permission runtime only for Android 12 and above

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S){
   //requesting permission only for Android 12 and above
                Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN,
                Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT,
                Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE,
 }
```

Note: other permissions also as normally requested