# Bluetooth FINE_LOCATION and COARSE_LOCATION Permissions on Android 11 or lower

Tags: android, permissions, bluetooth, android-11

I want to connect and communicate with an Android device via a Bluetooth SPP socket. Therefore, I need to specify the correct Bluetooth permissions in the Manifest and request them at runtime in the app.

According to the official [Bluetooth permission documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/permissions#declare-android11-or-lower), on Android 11 or lower, I need to request the following permissions:

- BLUETOOTH
- BLUETOOTH_ADMIN
- ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION

However it is stated:

> If your app targets Android 9 (API level 28) or lower, you **can** declare the ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permission instead of the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission.

Therefore, I would expect that I don't need to declare ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, even for Android 9 or lower.

Nevertheless, the IDE states:

> If you need access to FINE location, you must request both ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION and ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION

Why do i need to request booth ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION and ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permissions, shouldn't it be sufficient to only request ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION?

The permission requirements are fulfilled when I request both but i want to keep my code clean and minimal in addition to understanding the permission guidelines.

Comment: `Why do i need to request booth ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION and ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permissions, should it be sufficient to only request ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION?` You already know. As just above that sentence you quoted the docs tyat you should. And why? Google decided it like that. Anything against it?

Comment: "@blackapps, I understand your point, but according to Android Studio (v. 8), it seems that the IDE is suggesting something different. While I'm aware that IDE suggestions should not always be taken at face value, I would have expected Android Studio to be knowledgeable about the required permissions and not flag this as an error.

Comment: Hey @Leo, in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72842249/12749998) I covered completely how to request permissions for all API levels upto API level 32 (Android 12) in java. Also you'll see the OP's implementation in Kotlin. Check it out and just don't mind what the IDE says.

Comment: AFAIK, when you add both `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` and `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` user will be prompted to select either precise location or approximate one. Otherwise user will be asked to grant only Precise location which may get denied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that **for Bluetooth connectivity**, the ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permission **is not necessary**. The IDE suggestion to request both ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION and ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permissions may not be applicable in the context of Bluetooth communication. It seems to be more likely a generic recommendation based on typical location-based app development scenarios than a really need...

**In the case of Bluetooth**, the requirement is typically limited to **ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION** permission. The ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permission is not specifically required for Bluetooth functionality. There is even no statement in [provided documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/permissions#declare-android11-or-lower) that you can declare ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permission instead of the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission at Android 9 (API level 28) or lower. On the contrary there is written following statement:

> ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION is necessary because, on Android 11 and lower, a Bluetooth scan could potentially be used to gather information about the location of the user.

**To summarize:**

For Bluetooth connectivity, you should declare and request the BLUETOOTH and BLUETOOTH_ADMIN permissions in your app's manifest.

Additionally, you should declare and request the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission, as Bluetooth scans are considered a form of location access starting from Android 6.0 (API level 23).

The IDE suggestion to request both ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION and ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permissions might be a generic recommendation based on typical location-based app development scenarios. However, in the case of Bluetooth communication, it is sufficient to request only the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission.