# BLE Scanner in Android doesn't find anything on Scan Results

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth-lowenergy, esp32, arduino-esp32

I have been building an App, that should connect to an ESP32 Module with BLE
support to send and receive UTF-8 Messages between both devices. Unfortunately though
I am stuck at a certain point where I don't see my mistake and neither get any
error messages to identify what the issue might be.

The Bluetooth Adapter of my Mobile Phone scans as usually and seems to work fine
(though as ordered it only looks in low power mode which means only BLE devices appear
and therefore none appear which is the problem)

The ESP32 Module is not the issue because it runs well with nRF Connect but my App just doesn't
find it.

Here is a look into my Bluetooth Class I have built (I am sorry I am a newbie in Android Development you might take a shit on my code but I just need a resolution of my issue):

````
   lateinit var context: Context
   var bluetoothManager: BluetoothManager
   var bluetoothAdapter: BluetoothAdapter
   var bluetoothLeScanner: BluetoothLeScanner
   private var SERVICE_UUID: UUID = UUID.fromString("4fafc201-1fb5-459e-8fcc-c5c9c331914b")
   private var serviceUUIDs = arrayOf(SERVICE_UUID)
   var myDevices = HashMap<Int, BluetoothDevice>()
   var deviceCounter = 0
   var scanning = false
   var handler = Handler()
   val TAGe: String = "JOST_TAG_ERROR::  "
   val TAGs: String = "JOST_TAG_SUCCESS::  "
   lateinit var scanFilters: List<ScanFilter>
   val scanSettings: ScanSettings = ScanSettings.Builder()
       .setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_POWER)
       .setCallbackType(ScanSettings.CALLBACK_TYPE_ALL_MATCHES)
       .setMatchMode(ScanSettings.MATCH_MODE_AGGRESSIVE)
       .setNumOfMatches(ScanSettings.MATCH_NUM_MAX_ADVERTISEMENT)
       .setReportDelay(0)
       .build()

   @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.S)
   constructor(transmitted_context: Context){
       this.context = transmitted_context
       bluetoothManager = transmitted_context.getSystemService(BluetoothManager::class.java)
       bluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.adapter
       bluetoothLeScanner = bluetoothAdapter.bluetoothLeScanner

       if(serviceUUIDs != null){
           scanFilters = ArrayList<ScanFilter>()
           for(service: UUID in serviceUUIDs) {
               val filter = ScanFilter.Builder()
                   .setServiceUuid(ParcelUuid(SERVICE_UUID))
                   .build()
               (scanFilters as ArrayList<ScanFilter>).add(filter)
           }
       }

       this.lookingfordevices()
       this.scanLeDevice()
   }

   var scanCallback: ScanCallback = object : ScanCallback() {
       @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.S)
       override fun onScanResult(callbackType: Int, result: ScanResult) {
           Toast.makeText(context, "Starting onScanResult", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
           var bluetoothGatt: BluetoothGatt? = null
           var device: BluetoothDevice = result.device as BluetoothDevice
           Toast.makeText(context, ""+result.device.uuids.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
           myDevices[deviceCounter] = device
           deviceCounter++
           if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                   context,
                   Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
               ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
           ) {
               ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(context as Activity, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT), 1)
           }
           if ((result != null) && result.device.uuids.contentEquals(serviceUUIDs)) {
               Toast.makeText(context, "Scanresult isn't null and device UUID fits", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
               bluetoothGatt = result.device.connectGatt(context, false, bluetoothGattCallback,
                   BluetoothDevice.TRANSPORT_LE
               )
               Toast.makeText(context, "Connecting ot Gatt: "+bluetoothGatt.device.address,
                   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

           } else {
               Log.e(TAGe, "THERE ARE NO DEVICES FOUND FROM YOUR SCAN RESULT")
               Toast.makeText(context, "There are no devices found!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
           }
       }

       override fun onScanFailed(errorCode: Int) {
           super.onScanFailed(errorCode)
           Toast.makeText(context, "onScan Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
       }

   }

   private val bluetoothGattCallback = object: BluetoothGattCallback() {
       @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.S)
       override fun onConnectionStateChange(gatt: BluetoothGatt?, status: Int, newState: Int) {
           if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
               ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(context as Activity, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT),1)
           }
           if(status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS){
               Toast.makeText(context, "GATT_SUCCESS", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
               if(newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED){
                   Toast.makeText(context, "GATT FINALLY CONNECTED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                   var bondstate = gatt?.device?.bondState
                   if(bondstate == BluetoothDevice.BOND_NONE || bondstate == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED){
                       gatt?.discoverServices()
                   } else if (bondstate == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDING){
                       Toast.makeText(context, "Waiting Bonding to complete", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                   }
               } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED){
                   gatt?.close()
               } else {
                   //TODO
               }
           } else {
               Toast.makeText(context, "NO SUCCES IN GATT", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
               gatt?.close()
           }
       }
   }



   private val SCAN_PERIOD: Long = 10000
   //stops scanning after 10 seconds


   fun scanLeDevice(){
       Toast.makeText(context, "Scanning Devices", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
       if(bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled){
           Toast.makeText(context, "b_adapter_enabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
           if(!scanning){
               Toast.makeText(context, "Scanning was false", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
               handler.postDelayed({
                   scanning = false
                   if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                           context,
                           Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN
                       ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                   ) {
                       ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                           context as Activity,
                           arrayOf(Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN), 1
                       )
                   }
                   bluetoothLeScanner.stopScan(scanCallback)
               }, SCAN_PERIOD)
               scanning = true
               Toast.makeText(context, "Starting Scan therefore", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
               bluetoothLeScanner.startScan(scanFilters,scanSettings,scanCallback)
           } else {
               Toast.makeText(context, "Scanned", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
               scanning = false
               bluetoothLeScanner.stopScan(scanCallback)
           }
       }
   }

   fun lookingfordevices(){
       CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
           handler.postDelayed({
               Log.d(TAGs, myDevices.size.toString())
               scanLeDevice()
               lookingfordevices()
           },15000)
       }
   }

   @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.S)
   fun checkinitialpermissionstate(){
       if(!PermissionCheck().requestPermissionState(context)){
           PermissionCheck().requestPermissions(context)
       }
   }


}  ```
````

Comment: Have you ever tried without using scan filters and with default scan settings?

Comment: @Kozmotronik yes I have. No difference whatsoever

Comment: A side note on your statement _**though as ordered it only looks in low power mode**_: `SCAN_MODE_LOW_POWER` is not meant for scanning BLE devices but it is one of the scan modes of the BLE scanner API. When you scan devices using `bluetoothLeScanner.startScan` you already are scaning for BLE devices only.

Comment: Ah okay good to know. Though I have hangled through a tutorial for this certain app. Where I had to figure out based on what the guy explained what I needed. In this case, he used and recommended that one ScanSetting without any certain explanation.

I am still confused though why its not finding anything.

Also there is like `onScannerRegistered() - status=0 scannerId=16 mScannerId=0`

Comment: Do you know if that has anything to do with my issues ? I have Access Coarse and Fine Location permitted and Location Tracking is enabled whilst testing.

Comment: What is your Android's version? Or what is its SDK level?

Comment: I am using Android 7.0.0 Nougat for Emulator and tested phone is Android 12 MiUI
Poco X4 GT. I have done nothing over night now this shit actually picks up devices. IDK it works now.

Comment: For Android 12 and above you should declare and grant BLUETOOTH_SCAN for scanning and BLUETOOTH_CONNECT for connection operations. Check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72842249/12749998) where I describe (Java) how to request bluetooth permissions up to Android 13.

Comment: Thanks alot. This definetly wasn't the fix for my issues though. I have handled my Permissions like you did there in Java in a external Class and checked it through initial onCreate. It works flawlessly for now.

Comment: Does it find your device after implementing the missing permission?

Comment: As I said. The Permission was never missing. But the Bluetooth LE Device doesn't advertise with its UUID but rather with its MAC Address. Therefore I just searched for the MAC Address, connected it, retreived its services by UUID and characteristics by UUID. Now I can address it and write such as read from it. It works completely fine.

Comment: Glad for you! You can answer to your question and then accept your answer so that the others that may face the same problem would benefit of your experience. You know, this is how community grows.

Comment: I am a newbie on Stackoverflow how do I do that ?

Comment: There must be a button named **Answer Your Question** below of your question page. Click on that button and follow the instruction. Then simply tell how you could resolve your problem and post it. Then you will have to wait 48 hours to be able to accept your answer. Go ahead and try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final and obvious answer was: An BLE ESP32 Module does obviously not
advertise UUID Data of its services for characteristics. Therefore
hence it was more senseful to scan and connect to a device here by the MAC Address rather than the UUID information. The UUID information is still useful to have though because later on when addressing an ESP32 Module you might want to communicate with it via UTF-8 or other standards. The characteristics retrieved by such a device can be used to do exactly that.