# Bluetooth low energy permission error for android

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-permissions, logcat, android-bluetooth

I have created an App to scan and connect BLE devices, but unfortunately the app keeps crashing whenever the MainActivity(BLE Scan) is launched, please help me into find the error in my code as I have already implemented all necessary BLE permissions and runtime permissions.

Main Activity code

```
public class BluetoothScanning extends AppCompatActivity {

    private GifImageView imageView;
    private boolean isScanning = false;
    private BluetoothGatt bluetoothGatt;
    private BluetoothGattCallback gattCallback;

    private ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> enableBtLauncher;
    private BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
    private ArrayList<String> deviceList;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    private static final long SCAN_PERIOD = 60000; // 1 minute


    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
    private static final int REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION = 2;

    private ListView listView;

    private Button scan;



    private final BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                String deviceName = device.getName();
                String deviceAddress = device.getAddress();
                String deviceInfo = deviceName + "\n" + deviceAddress;
                if (!deviceList.contains(deviceInfo)) {
                    deviceList.add(deviceInfo);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bluetoothscanning);

        deviceList = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, deviceList);

        imageView = findViewById(R.id.gif);
        scan = findViewById(R.id.scanbutton);
        listView = findViewById(R.id.devicelist);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        scan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startBluetoothScan();
            }
        });

        enableBtLauncher = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
                result -> {
                    if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                        startBluetoothScan();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth is required for this app to function", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });



        bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        if (bluetoothAdapter == null) {
            // Device doesn't support Bluetooth
            Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth not supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            // Request Bluetooth and Location permissions at runtime
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN,Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION);
            } else {
                // Permissions are already granted, start scanning
                scan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        startBluetoothScan();
                    }
                });

                if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                    Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                    enableBtLauncher.launch(enableBtIntent);
                } else {
                    // Bluetooth is already enabled, start scanning
                    startBluetoothScan();
                }

                listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                        String deviceInfo = adapter.getItem(i);
                        String[] parts = deviceInfo.split("\n");
                        String deviceAddress = parts[1]; // Assuming the device address is the second part of the split string

                        // Call the method to connect to the selected Bluetooth device
                        connectToBluetoothDevice(deviceAddress);
                    }
                });





                }
            }


        }

    private void connectToBluetoothDevice(String deviceAddress) {
        BluetoothManager bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        bluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();
        BluetoothDevice device = bluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(deviceAddress);

        gattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
                super.onConnectionStateChange(gatt, status, newState);
                if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                    // Device connected. Discover services here if necessary.
                } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
                    // Device disconnected. Handle disconnection here.
                }
            }

            // Other callback methods for BLE operations can be implemented here
        };

        // Connect to the BLE device
        bluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(this, false, gattCallback);
    }

    // Your existing methods



    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        registerReceiver(bluetoothStateReceiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND));
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        unregisterReceiver(bluetoothStateReceiver);
        stopScan();
    }




    private void startBluetoothScan() {
        if (bluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
            bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        }
        bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
        // Register for broadcasts when a device is discovered
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, filter);

        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                stopScan();
            }
        }, SCAN_PERIOD);

        isScanning = true;
        scan.setText("Stop Scan");
    }

    public void stopScan() {
        scan.setText("Scan Again");
        bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null); // Remove any pending callbacks
        isScanning = false;
        // Change the image in the ImageView here
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.bluetoothscanningfail);
    }



    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (bluetoothAdapter != null) {
            bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        }
        // Unregister the broadcast receiver
        unregisterReceiver(bluetoothStateReceiver);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Permission granted, start scanning
                startBluetoothScan();
            } else {
                // Permission denied, handle accordingly
                Toast.makeText(this, "Location permission is required for Bluetooth scanning", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BT) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // Bluetooth is enabled, start scanning
                startBluetoothScan();
            } else {
                // User denied enabling Bluetooth, handle this scenario accordingly
                Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth is required for this app to function", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }


    private final BroadcastReceiver bluetoothStateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();

            if (action.equals(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED)) {
                final int state = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE,
                        BluetoothAdapter.ERROR);
                switch (state) {
                    case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF:
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Please TURN ON Bluetooth", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        // Bluetooth has been turned off;
                        break;
                    case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_OFF:
                        // Bluetooth is turning off;
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Bluetooth is Turning OFF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON:
                        // Bluetooth is on
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Bluetooth is ON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_ON:
                        // Bluetooth is turning on
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Bluetooth is Turning ON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    };
}
```

manifest file permissions

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />
```

LogCat error

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: com.example.digilocktrial, PID: 26896
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.digilocktrial/com.example.digilocktrial.BluetoothScanning}: java.lang.SecurityException: Need android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN permission for AttributionSource { uid = 10187, packageName = com.example.digilocktrial, attributionTag = null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@487b245, next = null }: AdapterService isDiscovering
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3782)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3922)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:139)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:96)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2443)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)
  Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Need android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN permission for AttributionSource { uid = 10187, packageName = com.example.digilocktrial, attributionTag = null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@487b245, next = null }: AdapterService isDiscovering
    at com.android.bluetooth.Utils.checkPermissionForDataDelivery(Utils.java:554)
    at com.android.bluetooth.Utils.checkScanPermissionForDataDelivery(Utils.java:613)
    at com.android.bluetooth.btservice.AdapterService$AdapterServiceBinder.isDiscovering(AdapterService.java:2342)
    at com.android.bluetooth.btservice.AdapterService$AdapterServiceBinder.isDiscovering(AdapterService.java:2332)
    at android.bluetooth.IBluetooth$Stub.onTransact(IBluetooth.java:1024)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1344)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1275)
```

Comment: BLUETOOTH_SCAN is a runtime permission that you must ask for at runtime, in addition to having it in the manifest. See https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.

Comment: Removed `android-studio` tag as that tag is for questions/issues with the Android Studio product. Your question has nothing to do with Android Studio.

Comment: In `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{});` I don't see the `BLUETOOTH_SCAN` permission string included. The error message indicates this problem: You don't request a runtime permission for `BLUETOOTH_SCAN`. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72842249/12749998) where I show an example implmentation of requesting runtime permissions for bluetooth.